# How to append a value from a dictionary into a list of dictionaries under certain conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have two list of dictionaries. I would like to append to the nested dictionary of `list_dicts1`, when the corresponding name in the text of `list_dicts2` appears. E.g. in `list_dicts2`, the name 'Nat' appears in two different texts, so I would like to append that to the nested dictionary containing 'Nat' in `list_dicts1`

Problem: my code creates a new dictionary entry when the name appears in more than one text, rather than appending it to the same dictionary.

```
list_dicts1= [{'id': '1', 'name': 'John', 'nested':[{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'}]},
              {'id': '2', 'name': 'Nat', 'nested':[{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'}]}]
```

```
list_dicts2=[{'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'},
             {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'},
             {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{'id': '1',
  'name': 'John',
  'nested': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'},
   {'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'}]},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'Nat',
  'nested': [{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'},
   {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'},
   {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]}]
```

My code:

```
  for d in list_dicts1:
        for dic in list_dicts2: 
            if d.get('name', '') in dic.get('text', ''):
                d["nested"].append(dic)
                print(d)
```

Current output:

```
[{'id': '1',
  'name': 'John',
  'nested': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'},
   {'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'}]},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'Nat',
  'nested': [{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'},
   {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'}]},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'Nat',
  'nested': [{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'},
   {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'},
   {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]}]
```

As you can see a new 'Nat' entry is created in the current output, which is not the idea.
I hope my question is clear enough (its easiest to reproduce by pasting these dictionaries into your editor). I reproduced this issue in my code before posting the question.

Comment: When I try running your code, I get the correct output.

Comment: Can you show me with clarity?

Comment: I honestly do not get the desired output.

Comment: is the current "output" from the `print` statement there?

Comment: the current output is the result of the print statement. But i would like it to look like the "desired output"

Comment: that print statement is executed at each iteration. shouldn't you be runnin the print at the end once?

Comment: move the print statement to outside of "`for d in list_dicts1`" block

Comment: @blah Take a look at my answer; this was the code I ran.

Comment: so your answer gives the correct output to this question - but  unfortunately its not what im looking for because "list_dicts1" is actually a solr database object (in my code), but I tried to reproduce it here with dummy data. The problem i am trying to solve is not well written in my own question in the end, yet it is difficult to reproduce on stackoverflow -  but Ill accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `print` statement outside of the for-loop, you should get the correct output.

```
list_dicts1= [{'id': '1', 'name': 'John', 'nested':[{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'}]},
              {'id': '2', 'name': 'Nat', 'nested':[{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'}]}]

list_dicts2=[{'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'},
             {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'},
             {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]

for d in list_dicts1:
    for dic in list_dicts2: 
        if d.get('name', '') in dic.get('text', ''):
            d["nested"].append(dic)
            
print(list_dicts1) # Prints the desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the value for key `'name'` is in the values for key `'text'`, if that is the case add the whole dictionary to the key `'nested'`

```
import pprint


list_dicts1= [{'id': '1', 'name': 'John', 'nested':[{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'}]},
              {'id': '2', 'name': 'Nat', 'nested':[{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'}]}]

list_dicts2=[{'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'},
             {'id': 'B', 'text': 'this text contains the name Nat'},
             {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]

for dictionary in list_dicts1:
  for b_dict in list_dicts2:
    if dictionary['name'] in b_dict['text']:
      dictionary['nested'] = [dictionary['nested'][0],b_dict]

pprint.pprint(list_dicts1)

>>> [{'id': '1',
  'name': 'John',
  'nested': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'text1'},
             {'id': 'A', 'text': 'this text contains the name John'}]},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'Nat',
  'nested': [{'id': '2', 'text': 'text2'},
             {'id': 'C', 'text': 'this text also contains the name Nat'}]}]
```

This line

```
[dictionary['nested'][0],b_dict]
```

returns the dictionary inside list for key `'nested'` since this value is initially a list with one dictionary inside and also `b_dict` is just a dictionary.